# Change the folder that WebJars are put in

Tags: playframework, webjars

I'm using Play with WebJars which is working great but I'd like to change the directory where the WebJar dependencies get put. At the moment they are all put in `assets/lib`.

I it possible to change this location in build.sbt or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the URL that the assets are accessed with then you can change your routes, like:

```
GET   /webjars/*file   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public/lib", file: Asset)
```

If you want to change the dir they are stored in you can try to set `webModulesLib` in your `build.sbt` to a different dir.  You can see that setting in the `sbt-web` plugin that extracts the WebJars:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/web/SbtWeb.scala#L37

Comment: webModulesLib, that's what I was looking for :)